Connecting to the google meets api using a service account, and don’t know what to call on new SpacesServiceClient().createSpace()
import { JWT } from "google-auth-library";
import { SpacesServiceClient } from "@google-apps/meet";

  const jwtClient = new JWT({
    email: "some-email",
    key: "some-key,
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.created"],
  });

  const meetClient = new SpacesServiceClient({
    authClient: jwtClient,
  });
  // Construct request
  const request = {};

  // Run request
  const response = await meetClient.createSpace();
  console.log(`Meet URL: ${response[0].meetingUri}`);

To explain what I did here, I used my service account credentials to get a jwtClient. Then I get he meetClient from there. Finally, I make a call to create a space(), but it seems like there is an error.
I got the example from the official docs here: https://developers.google.com/meet/api/guides/meeting-spaces. After running the code, it seems to give me an error of "details: 'Permission denied on resource Space (or it might not exist)'".
I tried looking at the types of the parameters expected, but they seem to be optional parameters.

For anyone who is struggling like i did , here is the solution
import { SpacesServiceClient, protos } from '@google-apps/meet';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';  
import { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth';
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

 SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.created',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.readonly' 
 ];

createMeetSpace(): string {
  this.authorize().then(this.createSpace).catch(console.error);
   return 
}


async authorize() {
 const saclient = new JWT(
  "serviceaccountemail@xyz.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  null,
  "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  this.SCOPES,
  'yourimpersonatingemail@domain.com' // this email should be part of your workspace account
 );
  return saclient;
}

async createSpace(authClient) {
  const meetClient = new SpacesServiceClient({
    authClient: authClient
  });
  // Construct request
  const request = {   
    space: {
     config :{ 
      accessType:1 // for open access to meeting link
     }
   }
  }

  // Run request
  const response = await meetClient.createSpace(request);
  meetClient.descriptors
  console.log(`Meet URL: ${response[0].meetingUri}`);
}


I had a similar problem with this api but i was using php. Your problem is caused because you don't have domain wide delegation. If you don't have a google work space business account with approved domain (basically adding some values to your dns records from your domain registrar's website google will tell you how you need to done) you need to create one. Then you need to give access to related oauth scopes from admin.google.com to your service account. Finally you can edit your code to impersonate your admin account, i don't know how it's done in nodejs spesifically but you can check my answer in php there.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78406736/15530978

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
